# Goで幅優先探索をしてみようとして不思議な挙動に出会う

Tags: アルゴリズム, go

お気楽goプログラミングというサイト
http://www.geocities.jp/m_hiroi/golang/puzgo01.html
で幅優先探索を学んでいましたが、
makePathを使うところでappendと使うと
[0 2 4 6]を２回出力します。
プリントデバッグしたところ何度か同じものをキューに入れていますが
どうしてそのような動きをしているのかわかりません
appendでスライスに元となる配列部分を超えたところに代入をしようとすると元の配列をコピーした別の配列を作りその配列を参照しようとしているのだと思っていましたがそこが間違いではないかと思います。
元となるものではどうしてmakePathを定義したのか、私のプログラムはなぜ失敗したのか教えてください。
コードは
https://play.golang.org/p/8s1-bf7qFd
に置きました。

Comment: ソースコードをそのままコピーして実行しましたがそのような現象は起きないようです。http://play.golang.org/p/8a0MQhcnBr

Comment: nitibo さんが試したソースそのものを play.golang.org などで公開すると、原因がわかると思われます。

Answer (score 1):

`append`したときにコピーが返されるのは配列のキャパシティが不足したときです。

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1,2,3,4}

    fmt.Println(cap(a))           // => 4
    fmt.Println(cap(a[:3]))       // => 4

    fmt.Println(append(a[:3], 5)) // => [1 2 3 5]
    fmt.Println(a)                // => [1 2 3 5]

    b := append(a[:4], 5)         // キャパシティ不足
    fmt.Println(append(b[:3], 6)) // => [1 2 3 6]
    fmt.Println(a)                // => [1 2 3 5]
}
```

また、`append`したあとのスライスのサイズとキャパシティが一致するとは限りません。
以下のコードを実行してみるとキャパシティは8なのでまだコピーなしで`append`できる余裕があります。

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1,2,3,4}
    b := []int{5,6}
    c := append(a, b...)
    fmt.Println(len(c), cap(c)) // => 6 8
}
```

よって、質問者さんのコードでは`append`したときにスライスがコピーされる保証がありません。

スライスを確実にコピーしたい場合は、空の配列と`append`するという方法があります。
つまり、`makePath`はもっと短く書くことができます。

```
func makePath(path []int, x int) []int {
    return append(append([]int(nil), path...), x)
}
```